# Where does this commutator relation come from?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

What is the origin of this relation:

$$  [H,a_n^\dagger] = \epsilon_n a_n^\dagger $$

for Hamiltonian $H$, creation operator $ a_n^\dagger $, and eigenvalue $ \epsilon_n $. The square brackets denote the commutator.

Is it derived from Ehrenfest's theorem? If so, how?

EDITED:

The context of this relation comes from p 56 of Advanced Solid State Physics by Philip Philips:

> The single-particle energies are defined through the operator equations of motion: 
>   $$  [H,a_n^\dagger] = \epsilon_n a_n^\dagger $$
>   To evaluate the commutator in [the above equation], we use the commutators ...

I ask about Ehrenfest's theorem because the author mentioned equations of motion.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! What's the context in which you found this? Is it the quantum harmonic oscillator, or QFT, or something else?

Comment: @lenzinho : who told you of Ehrenfest in connection with the commutator of which you ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't tell us what is the Hamiltonian. In what I say here I use the harmonic oscillator. Perhaps this calculus will inspire you for another domain of QT which works with the 2nd quantization. About Ehrenfest theorem I see no need here.

In the harmonic oscillator, which could describe a single mode of the electromagnetic field - let's label it by the subscript $n$ - the Hamiltonian is defined as :

$\hat H_n = h\nu _n (a^†_n a_n +1/2) = \epsilon _n (a^†_n a_n +1/2)$.

Indeed, $h\nu_n$ is the energy of a photon in the mode $n$, the operator $a^†a$ is the number operator, s.t. for an eigenvalue $N_n$ of the number operator we have the energy $N_n \epsilon_n$. The residual energy $\epsilon _n /2$ is an effect with different explanations in which I won't get here.

Now, let's calculate the commutator:

$[H_n, a^†_n] = \epsilon _n (a^†_n a_n +1/2) a^†_n - a^†_n \epsilon _n (a^†_n a_n +1/2) 
=\epsilon _n a^†_n (a_n a^†_n - a^†_n a_n)$ .

We have the following identity (you can check it)

$[a_n, a^†_m] = \delta^{Kronecker}_{n,m}$.

Thus we remain with

$[H_n, a^†_n] = \epsilon _n a^†_n$

as you asked.

Comment: This isn't "optics" it's just harmonic oscillator. Nothing in this answer is restricted to light.

Comment: @DanielSank : I didn't say that my answer is **restricted** to light. Please read again. It's written there "and maybe this calculus will **inspire** you for another domain of QT which works with the 2nd quantization". By the time I answered it wasn't written in the question that it is about harmonic oscillator. David asked, but there was no answer to that. Where do you see that it is the harmonic oscillator? Even now I don't see.

Comment: @DanielSank : and if it is harmonic oscillator, what's the difference? The formalism in terms of rising and lowering operators is the same.

Comment: Indeed the Hamiltonian for a mode of the EM field is a harmonic oscillator. However, the term "optics" implies something *more specific* than the harmonic oscillator, namely light. Since nothing in your answer is specific to light, why not just say that you're discussing the "harmonic oscillator" instead of "quantum optics"?

Comment: No problem. I specified that for the harmonic oscillator the treatment in terms of lowering and rising operators I the same. Would you have a look? But just a bit, to save the explanation.

Comment: @Will you look now? It's better to say that the treatment is good in both cases.

Comment: Sofia, I made a small additional edit to smooth the language and emphasize the fact that the optics case is a special case of the harmonic oscillator. If you do not like the edit you can always revert.

Comment: @DanielSank: but why do you think that telling that for the e.m. field it goes the same, it's harmful? Please tell me, in QFT (which I didn't learn) there are no such things? I believe that wherever it goes with raising and lowering operators, the equations are the same. (Except, probably, for fermions - in which case it has to be said in the answer.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19822/discussion-between-danielsank-and-sofia).